# Trying to get the value of a textarea when a page is submitted

Tags: c#, jquery

Hi I have textarea on a control page, which using jQuery I've 'turned' into a simple HTML Text editor (allowing users to embolden text and create simple unordered lists).

When the page is submitted I'm trying to get the value that's in the textarea and process into a database (keeping the html markup that's inside the textarea) but I can't find the control and therefore can't get the markup that's inside it.

So the page is something like (It's on the servers at work so this is from memory).

```
<div id="zone">
   <textarea id="txtDescription" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
```

And when the form is submitted I'm running

```
HtmlTextArea zArea = (HtmlTextArea)Page.FindControl("txtDescription");
```

Although I get no errors the value of zArea is always null.

It could be that I'm going about this the wrong way so any help would be greatly welcome.

Thanks,
Craig

EDITED****
Applying the runat=server method allows me to reference the value in the code behind page but I'm now struggling to 'find' the control with jQuery. The master page includes the jQuery code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ctl00_myJobZoneAddition_txtHTMLArea').jqte();
    });
</script>
```

This master page has a reference to the control.ascx page

```
<myWeb:JobZoneAddition ID="myJobZoneAddition" runat="server"/>
```

and on this control exists the actual text area:

```
<textarea id="txtHTMLArea" runat="server" cols="20" class="jobDescription" name="txtHTMLArea" rows="8"></textarea>
```

Any help on how to gain access to this textarea without naming ctl00_myJobZoneAddition_txtHTMLArea would be greatly received.

Thanks again

Comment: I'm not a .NET developer, but I suppose this is a .NET question. Stating only that it is C# is rather useless, or not?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you must add property runat with value "server", to your control

```
 <textarea id="txtDescription" cols="20" rows="2" runat="server"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your responses, sorry I should have said that when I add runat="server" to my control the jQuery text editor ceases to work. Presumably because the control is no longer being rendered on the client.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the **runat="server"** attribute to your textarea control, you will be able to access your control from the code-behind like so:

```
string description = txtDescription.value;
```

**EDIT:** based on your comment to my answer, it would seem you need to use the client ID. When you add **runat="server"** to the control, it will be visible in the code-behind. However, you cannot access that control the same way now from the client-side (e.g. your jQuery). You must use what is known as the **ClientID** of the control, rather than the ID attribute you normally would use. Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= txtDescription.ClientID %>').click(...)
});
```

If you run your application and look at the source code, you can see that 'txtDescription' gets replaced by a unique value. This value is known as the Client ID.

Comment: Hi thanks for your responses, sorry I should have said that when I add runat="server" to my control the jQuery text editor ceases to work. Presumably because the control is no longer being rendered on the client.

Comment: That's extremely helpful Sam. I shall try that first thing in the morning and I shall return with hopefully more thanks and a cheesy grin!

Comment: @user1551691 I'm glad you find it helpful! Hopefully it answers the question tomorrow then. And if not, we can keep trying.

Comment: You are an absolute legend! I could be being a spacca here but I couldn't exactly use the code that you mentioned above. Like you say though viewing the source after the page is rendered gives me, what I presume is, the client id so....

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ctl00_myJobZoneAddition_txtDescription').jqte();
        });
    </script>

Works a treat :) although now I'm into "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" and the hits just keep on coming!!!

Thank you Sam you're an international hero!

Comment: @user1551691 I'm glad you were able to get a better idea from this. However, I wouldn't suggest using the actual client ID that gets rendered (the one you see in source code). I apologize as I'm now realizing my code was missing a character, the equals sign (I edited the post to contain this now). Edit your script by replacing **ct100_myJobZoneAddition_txtDescription** with **<%= txtDescription.ClientID %>** ... this should work for you now.

Comment: Sorry for my tardiness, I shall try that tomorrow

Comment: Hi Sam, Sadly this didn't work out.

The error that I'm receiving is that txtDescription doesn't exist in the current context :(

Comment: Good morning. Can you please edit your original question to include the updated code that you're trying? I'd like to see how your jQuery text editor is configured to ensure we're calling it correctly.

Comment: Hi Sam, I'll do that this morning. Thanks again for your time